# Server Error in '/' Application.Runtime Error

Tags: c#

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="11000" 
             requestLengthDiskThreshold="80"
             useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
             minFreeThreads="8" 
             minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
             appRequestQueueLimit="5000"
             enableKernelOutputCache="true"
             enableVersionHeader="true"
             requireRootedSaveAsPath="true" enable="true"
             shutdownTimeout="90" delayNotificationTimeout="5" 
             waitChangeNotification="0" maxWaitChangeNotification="0" 
             enableHeaderChecking="true" sendCacheControlHeader="true" 
             apartmentThreading="false"/>
  <trust level="Full"/>
  <customErrors mode="on" defaultRedirect="~/Contents/error.aspx">
  </customErrors>
```

This is my error handling in `web.config` which is not working.

If there is any exception thrown it doesn't redirect to `/Contents/error.aspx` page 
Is it because I set /Contents/error.aspx -

If not what's wrong with the error handling.

Comment: set `<customErrors mode="Off" />` to see the actual error..

Comment: If you're not trapping and displaying the error in your custom page, read the message. It's something like "To view the error details, set customErrors to off in your web.config". Set it to off. That'll show you what's wrong until you handle it properly in your custom error page.

Comment: It is possible that your code is not compiling

Comment: Im pretty sure in c# when using directories you have to use 2 '/' ... //Contents//error.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the virtual directory as an ASP.NET application for the right framework version?

> This error can be caused by a virtual
>   directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

In IIS, you can have several applications, but they must be configured as an application.  Generally, when you create a web project it maps directly to an IIS application.

Check with your hosting service on how to create an IIS application for your web app.

See [IIS Setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx)

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890207/server-error-in-application-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Try using two '/' in the directory:

```
    //Contents//error.aspx
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

set customErrors mode="Off" in the web.config to see the actual error. As suggested by Sachin. It turned out to be a compilation Error I had to fix and could enable customErrors again.