# Missing IIS user friendly response for bad request (400)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

Our production sites return yellow screen as response in case of bad request.

Most of the asp.net bases sites including asp.net, MSDN even in local environment  IIS return a user friendly response.
what am I missing? our sites are hosted at IIS8

Comment: Custom error settings?

Answer (score -1):

In your web.config, turn debug to false and custom errors on. You can also name the page you want to to redirect to see this post [Server Error in '/' Application. ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890207/server-error-in-application-asp-net). That should do it.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```