# Server Error in '/admin' Application....An application error occurred on the server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 projects in my solution (ASP.NET MVC 5), one for the client and one for the admin. Both projects are running fine locally. But when I publish the admin project (which is located in the path: `root/admin` in my hosting) I'm getting the next error:

[image]

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Something to know, I have added:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

But i don't see any specific error and also I have configured the virtual directory `root/admin` as an application in IIS.

I know this is a common error but I don't see any solution like this one: [Server Error in '/' Application. ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890207/server-error-in-application-asp-net)

Comment: Make sure you are using the `Debug` publishing profile to be able to see the detailed error

Comment: I used the Debug publishing profile, but i don't see any specific error yet @mamodom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6679286/2958543

`<remove name="Data.Models.ApplicationDbContext" />`

after my connectionString.

Answer (score 2):

> The entry "Data.Models.ApplicationDbContext" has already been added.

That along with the Source File being the `web.config`, I'd look to see if that ApplicationDbContext is in the web.config twice and causing an issue in loading the application.

---

In the error message above is this reference:

> e:\Web\deliver4\admin\web.config line: 18

So, what are around line 18 in that web.config file?

Comment: I dont see any ApplicationDbContext in my web.config @JB King

Comment: I entered via ftp with FileZilla, and i downloaded the web.config and i see in the line 18 this: 

<add name="Data.Models.ApplicationDbContext" connectionString="Data.Models.ApplicationDbContext_ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

But locally in my project i dont see that. What shoud i do? @JB Kind

Comment: Are there any scripts being run to do the publish of the website? Perhaps something is adding that connection string?

Comment: there isn't any script, i do the publish manually with Visual Studio.The web.config is the same in the client project, but the client does not add that line, i dont know why the admin project is doing that.

Comment: What are other lines just before and after that line? Chances are there is another connection string with the same name and that is what is causing the error

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:s07.winhost.com;Initial Catalog=DB_2344_dlvd1dev;User ID=DB_4564_dlvd1dev_user;Password=mypass;Integrated Security=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Data.Models.ApplicationDbContext" connectionString="Data.Models.ApplicationDbContext_ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
........

Comment: I deleted the line 18, and then upload manually with filezilla. The problem is solved, but now i need to know whats is adding that line to my web.config

Comment: I'd examine settings in Visual Studio and whatever else is used to do the publish.